# Decoding an mpf exif block in an MPO stereo image file

Tags: file, image-processing, file-format, exif

I am writing something to get at the information contained in an MPO multi-picture file produced by cameras such as the fuji 3D cameras.

I have the proposed spec, which is obviously written to confuse, and is available from here:
[CIPA multi picture spec PDF](http://www.cipa.jp/english/hyoujunka/kikaku/pdf/DC-007_E.pdf) and have navigated the normal exif parts and extracted the MFP information.

Section 5.2.3 which describes the header lists
The header lists:

```
4 byte endian flag
4 byte offset
-- start of MP Index --
2 byte count
12 byte version
12 byte number of images
12 byte MP entry
12 byte Individual unique ID list
12 byte total number of capture frames
4 byte offset to next IFD.
```

The diagram shows the MP Entry and Unique ID list pointing to a offset (which would make 12 bytes).
However, in the description that follows it shows that the MP entry should be 16 bytes for every image (which in my sample image with two images, it is), and the individual unique ID being 33 bytes for every image (my sample doesn't have this).

Up to the number of images, everything is as it should be. I have 2 images, the version is correct, and there appear to be 3 blocks (count).
However, the third block (which is the MP Entry) has the right code, the correct number of bytes and the correct type, but contains the following information

```
32 00 00 00  52 00 00 00  02 00 02 20  40 63  1B 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  02 00 02 00  EE 6F  1B 00
```

The text says the contents of this should be

```
offset   length   name
0x00     4        Individual Image attribute
0x04     4        individual Image Size
0x08     4        Individual image offset
0x10     2        dependant image 1 entry number
0x12     2        dependant image 2 entry number
```

Clearly that makes no sense that if there are two images (they are effectively 10MP jpegs) that they have a size of 52 bytes and 0.

Could anyone take a look at this and check I am not going mad in my interpretation of it, or does anyone know what should be here?

Sorry, I know it is a bit complicated but I really cannot see where this is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the base address is 8 bytes into the APP2 header, just after the "MPF\0" and right before "II*\0", assuming little endian. In the hex dump you've provided there's no MPO tag included but I guess "32 00 00 00" points to the offset of the MPEntries and "52 00 00 00" is the offset to the next IFD. What you want to be looking at is "02 00 02 20" which probably is the attribute of the first image.

Remember if the offset is "00 00 00 00", it's not relative but absolute.

Comment: Turns out the format doesn't match in a lot of places. That 02 00 02 20 is the attribute, and I have decoded that, but sadly it gets worse when you get into the rest of the spec. I asked fuji, but they say it is commercial confident information, so I have to work it out manually.

Comment: Well every field that is bigger than 4 bytes, that means the RATIONAL and SRATIONAL fields are also pointing to offsets relative to the endianess tag. No tag is larger than 12 bytes. Is it that you have problems with?

Answer (score 4):

I believe your tag is ok.

Chapter 5.2 (MP Extensions) of the spec states MP index IFD as following:

- **Count** (2 bytes)
- **MP Index Fields** (Overall structure Info)
- **Offset of Next IFD** (4 bytes)
- **Value** (MP Index IFD)

Up to the number of images, everything is fine, as per spec. Starting from the MP Entry tag the bytes should be parsed as following:
(I'll be using data parsed from my MPO file)

```
02 b0 07 00   20 00 00 00   32 00 00 00   52 00 00 00
02 00 02 20   00 13 18 00   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00
```

- 02-b0     - Tag ID (MP entry), 2 bytes
- 07-00     - Type (7 = undefined), 2
  bytes
- 20-00-00-00 - 32 (16 x NumberOfImages,
  two images in my file, this value was
  parsed before), 4 bytes
- 32-00-00-00 - Offset of First IFD (50
  bytes, starting from endianness tag),
  4 bytes

That's where MP entry data ends. It's weird that there are no **Individual Image Unique ID List** (b003) or **Total Number of Captured Frames** (b004) tags, maybe they aren't necessary. Anyway, the next 4 bytes show offset of the next IFD, i.e.:

- 52-00-00-00 - Offset of Next IFD (82
  bytes, starting from endiannesss
  tag), 4 bytes

First IFD (in my case) starts immediately after the offset of Next IFD:

- 02-00-02-20 - Individual Image attr., 4
  bytes
- 00-13-18-00 - Individual image size
  (which states for 1 577 728 bytes of
  data in my case), 4 bytes
- 00-00-00-00 - Individual image data
  offset (states for 0 in case of first
  image), 4 bytes
- 00-00 - Dependent image 1 (no
  dependent image), 2 bytes
- 00-00 - Dependent image 2 (no
  dependent image), 2 bytes

In your case, the data should be parsed as following:

```
32 00 00 00  52 00 00 00  02 00 02 20  40 63  1B 00 
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  02 00 02 00  EE 6F  1B 00
```

- 32-00-00-00 - Offset of First IFD (50
  bytes, starting from endianness tag),
  4 bytes
- 52-00-00-00 - Offset of Next IFD (82
  bytes, starting from endiannesss
  tag), 4 bytes
- 02-00-02-20 - Individual Image attr., 4
  bytes
- 00-13-18-00 - Individual image size
  (which states for 1 794 880 bytes of
  data), 4 bytes
- 00-00-00-00 - Individual image data
  offset (states for 0 in case of first
  image), 4 bytes
- 00-00 - Dependent image 1 (no
  dependent image), 2 bytes
- 00-00 - Dependent image 2 (no
  dependent image), 2 bytes

And starting next image's data:

- 02-00-02-00 - Individual Image attr., 4
  bytes
- EE-6F-1B-00 - Individual image size
  (which states for 1 798 126 bytes of
  data), 4 bytes
  etc.

### **ABOUT IMAGE SIZE AND OFFSETS**

Image size and offsets can confuse a bit. Spec says that:

> "Image size is the data between SOI
>   and EOI markers" (ch. 5.2.3.3.2)

and

> "Data offset (for the second image) is
>   specified relative to the address of
>   the MP Endian field in the MP Header"
>   (ch. 5.2.3.3.3)

Which I understand to be as following:

```
SOI---MPF_FIELDS-------------EOI 
      ^
      MP endian field
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXSOI--------------------------EOI
```

(first image, say, 2164288 bytes between SOI and EOI markers, including the markers. Second image, 2221368 bytes between SOI and EOI markers, including the markers. XXXXX states for offset)

Offset of the second image means that SOI marker is starting in `lengthOf(XXXXX)` bytes after MP endian marker, which is in the first image's MP field.
I suspect that if you subtract offset value from first image size, you should get MP Endian marker position.

Comment: By the way, **Count** tag (2 bytes) of MP Index IFD should provide you with the number of used tags, which in my case (and I believe, in yours too) is "3". That means that there are only 3 tags in MP Index IFD field, which are (in order they mentioned in the spec): MP Format version number, Number Of Images and MP Entry. No other tags (like Individual Image IDs, etc.) here.

Comment: Decoded another image, and sure enough it follows what you say. there are some issues, such as the description from the individual image info doesn't match the 2 x number of images part, but follows what you say, and a little confusion left in that my first image size was 2164288 with an offset of 0, the second is 2221368 with an offset of 2133174 (which would overlap the first).

Comment: I also found the missing info that I needed (the paralax value) was stored in the individual exif of the second image. That was probably the part I was missing.

Comment: @Pavel Both ImageUIDList and TotalFrames are optional values if you read page 28 in the standard http://www.cipa.jp/english/hyoujunka/kikaku/pdf/DC-007_E.pdf . Otherwise, thanks for a very good explanation of the MPO format.

Comment: @Woody You're right, I added some comments to the post (please refer to "About size and offsets").

@onemasse Thanks for mentioning page 28, I really missed this one.

Comment: @Pavel you point to the "M" in "MPF\0" as being the start of the endian marker, actually it's four bytes after. The endian marker is either "II*\0" or "MM\0*" if i remember correctly.

Comment: @Woody, could you please tell me what tag number the parallax value has?

Comment: 0xB211 from the exiftool info http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/FujiFilm.html  and as it says there, it only appears in the right image.