# Encoding and decoding 3D MPO File Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, 3d, jpeg

A MPO file is a file that contains two still images and is commonly used by 3D cameras.

I would like to convert two jpg images into one MPO file and also do the opposite.

My Platform for this is iOS (Objective C).

I already found this:
[Decoding an mpf exif block in an MPO stereo image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746272/decoding-an-mpf-exif-block-in-an-mpo-stereo-image-file)
but it is more or less the binary structure of such a MPO file. 
Does anyone knows an already existing converter to use in iOS or any hints to implement such a converter?

Regards Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no existing converters to do so, but using the info posted by pavel will let you stitch two images together. Sadly I didn't have a chance to look into it much after that due to job changes. I have recently just come back to it.

To stitch two images together you need to take two existing jpegs, take their data, and create the MPO header (which actually says very little, just how many images there are and what they do), and the data that shows the separation between the images, which is what I and pavel showed between us.

Additional complications looking into doing an iOS application, is you can't open MPOs automatically from the SD, as you have no access to that, or way of registering yourself as a handler for MPOs, as you could on OSX.